# Why doesn't Redux pass state to subscribed functions?

Tags: redux

Why doesn't Redux just push the new state to listeners (as a parameter) like many callbacks do?

```
for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
    listeners[i](currentState)
}
```

So we could...

```
store.subscribe(state => {
    // ...just use it here...
})
```

...instead of having to call

```
store.subscribe(() => {
    store.getState() // ?
})
```

Comment: The word 'subscribe' implies you are given something.  If you subscribe to a magazine they don't just call you and tell you a new issue is out.  If you are not receiving anything it seems like a different name would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it looks like this has been suggested numerous times in [Redux's issue tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues).

Here is what the devs have said about it:

[#303 (Jul 27, 2016)](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/303#issuecomment-125184409) "`subscribe` [is] a low level API." — [gaearon](https://github.com/gaearon), the project founder

[#1514 (Mar 11)](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1513#issuecomment-195351592) "In any case, having just the new state is not very useful. You’ll probably want the previous state too. And not just the previous state—probably a specific part you care about. At which point you might as well write your own helper to do this." — gaearon

[#1832 (Jun 27)](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1832#issuecomment-228938359)  "The short version is that Redux just provides the simplest API possible."

And that's just a few of them.  Tons of people have asked this question.

---

I would write a TL;DR here, but I don't feel like it.  So please do read anyway.   **:-)**